# Python Requests - Post indexed array

Tags: python, forms, python-requests

I'd like to send request using python and requests library. 
I have checked this request in web browser inspector and form data looks like that:

```
data[foo]: bar
data[numbers][]: 1
data[numbers][]: 2
data[numbers][]: 3
data[numbers][]: 4
data[numbers][]: 5
csrf_hash: 12345
```

This is my code:

```
payload = {'data[foo]': 'bar', 'csrf_hash': 12345,
         'data[numbers]': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
r = s.post('https://www.foo.com/bar/', payload)
```

It doesn't work. I'm getting error because of invalid post data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a modification to make it more dynamic:

Here is the code:

```
    payload = ['data[foo]': 'bar', 'csrf_hash': 12345]
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
    idx = 0
    for item in numbers:
        payload = payload  + [('data[numbers]' + '[' + str(idx) + ']', 
        str(numbers ))]
        idx = idx + 1
    r = s.post(*your_url_here*, payload)
```

Comment: If you do not want to hassle with the indices of the arrays, the [official](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files) method looks like this: `payload = [('data[foo]', 'bar'), ('data[numbers]', 1), ('data[numbers]', 2), …]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem realise in the way that you are trying to send the data to https://www.foo.com/bar/

instead of sending it using `data`I would recommend you to try `json` instead so your final code should look something like this

```
payload = {'data[foo]': 'bar', 'csrf_hash': 12345,
         'data[numbers]': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
r = s.post('https://www.foo.com/bar/', json=payload)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Your solution doesn't work in my case. I add my answer with way I handled it.

Comment: Worked for me!! I was using `artists[]` though in an upload form that was taking multiple artists.

Comment: Downvoted for not answering the question. JSON is not the same as a multipart form.

Comment: @Hermann Hey, where do you see anyone mention multipart forms?

Comment: @NazimKerimbekov I might have misunderstood OP's intentions. The question explicitly asks for "form data", has the tag "forms", and the given code example describes the key-value-pairs commonly found in `multipart/form-data` [encoding type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype). "Use JSON" may be a good advice, but OP does not seem to have the option of changing the server's interface to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a way to deal with it in a more dynamic / adaptable way.  What I came up with was this:

```
def multi_dict_to_php_dict(md):
    result = {}
    for key in md.keys():
        if '[]' in key:  # Key is an array, we need to make the array keys unique.
            keyformat = '[%d]'.join(key.split('[]'))
            for idx, val in enumerate(md.getlist(key)):
                result[keyformat % idx] = val
        else:  # Key is just a value, include it in the new result.
            result[key] = md[key]
    return result
```

This supports things like `number[]`, as well as `group[][name]` (what I was encountering) or `item[children][]`.  It wouldn't (in its current form) handle `arrayofarrays[][]`, but it could probably be made to with some minor adaptation.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to do this:

```
import json

url = 'https://www.foo.com/bar/'
payload = {'some': 'data'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Comment: Can you share what API you are trying to use?

Comment: It isn't API, it's normal web service. And I'd rather not to share its name